# Apache CXF malformed message exception

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, cxf

I am using Apache CXF inside a spring container exposing a web service annotated using JaxWS. All works fine but except one thing...

When I send a malformed message to the web server I see a stack trace is sent to System.err. Is there any way I can suppress the exception on the server side? This could be problematic if a incorrectly "coded" client keeps hitting this web server and stack traces flood the console/log.

In fact an exception is even thrown when I hit the URL in my browser.

Any input will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**
This is the exception I get

```
07 Feb 2012 9:39:02 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://ws.test.com/}MyEndpointImpService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /HelloWorld)
```

And More...

```
07 Feb 2012 10:00:29 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://ws.payd.oltio.com/}PayDEndpointImpService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader.
```

Comment: you should provide the method and the Exception and the XML Request that you send, probably the WSDl would not hurt also

Comment: It works just fine. its only when a malformed request is sent...

Comment: and by malformed you mean...? Wrong params? Wrong address? etc?

Comment: No closing tags etc. Basically any garbage that can be sent to the webserver. Anything other than a logic exception cause by my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the logging levels in your logging.properties, as shown in the [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-Configurelogginglevels.).

You could either remove the *ConsoleHandler*, or change the level to not log the WARNING messages.

Comment: And then how do I see "valid" warning log messages?

Comment: The messages are "valid", as they are caused by bad requests.  Unless I misunderstood the question?  You could log the messages to a FileHandler, and use a reasonable size limit to prevent the errors from getting out of hand.

Comment: Fair enough... I did the following: <logger name="org.apache.cxf.phase" level="ERROR" />. Thank you for your input.